# Upload local database to SkyDrive as a textfile

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, onedrive

I havent looked at the samples yet for the SkyDrive.
I have done a application that saves some data in a local database on the phone.

What i want to do is to upload all these to a SkyDrive account as a textfile.

Is this possible?

Comment: Query your database for data you want to upload, prepare txt file with that data and use SkyDrive SDK to upload it. Have you tried anything before asking the question?

Comment: I havent tried anything. Will test around and be back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to start with a blog post I wrote - [Adding SkyDrive support to your Windows Phone application](http://den.azurewebsites.net/adding-skydrive-upload-support-to-your-windows-phone-app). You will need to download the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff519582.aspx) (unless you want to use the REST API manually, which I can see no reason for at this point).

Uploading is fairly simple after that, given that you obtained the proper session init:

```
client = new LiveConnectClient(App.MicrosoftAccountSession);
client.UploadCompleted += MicrosoftAccountClient_UploadCompleted;
client.UploadProgressChanged += MicrosoftAccountClient_UploadProgressChanged;
client.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", Binder.Instance.CurrentlyUploading,
   stream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
```

Where `stream` is a `MemoryStream` instance.